# HOW TO SELECT MULTIPLE SHAPES (DRAG AND DROP) IN JAVA FX?

Tags: javafx-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBTZw.png)

i can't select multiple objects like rectangular and textfield . i need to select, drag and drop multiple shapes like word document...........anyone answer please......

```
public SelectionModel selectionModel;
public MouseHandler(SelectionModel selectionModel2, SelectionModel selectionModel     ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.selectionModel = selectionModel;
}

private class DragContext {
    double x;
    double y;
}

public void makeDraggable( final Node node) {
    final DragContext dragDelta = new DragContext();

    node.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {

        // TODO: add shift & ctrl check to add/remove nodes to selection
        selectionModel.clear();

        Group root=new Group();
        selectionModel.add(node);

        dragDelta.x = node.getTranslateX() - mouseEvent.getSceneX();
        dragDelta.y = node.getTranslateY() - mouseEvent.getSceneY();     

        mouseEvent.consume();            
    });

    node.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {       
        node.setTranslateX(mouseEvent.getSceneX() + dragDelta.x);
        node.setTranslateY(mouseEvent.getSceneY() + dragDelta.y);
    });

    node.setOnMouseReleased(mouseEvent -> {
        fixPosition(node);
    });
}

private void fixPosition( Node node) {

    double x = node.getTranslateX();
    double y = node.getTranslateY();

    node.relocate(node.getLayoutX() + x, node.getLayoutY() + y);

    node.setTranslateX(0);
    node.setTranslateY(0);
}
}
```

Please explain your answer with the code

Answer (score 0):

In your move node method which i dont see You have to loop through the selected nodes and apply your translation to all simultaneously.

If this doesnt help please be more specific :)